# How do I change part of a org.w3c.dom.Node using an xpath expression?

Tags: java, xpath, w3c

I'm using Java 6.  Given a org.w3c.dom.Node, how do change the contents of one of its child elements (or potentially the node itself), given an xpath String expression representing one of those elements?  Note by "contents", I'm always referring to text.  If the child element represented by the path expression contained other child elements, those should go away and replaced with the text I want to substitute.

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

First, you find the element that the XPath expression points to (using the simple [XPathAPI](http://svario.it/xpathapi))

```
// `node` is your node
// `xpathExpr` is a String with the XPath expression
// `elem` is is element pointed by the XPath expression

Node elem = XPathAPI.selectSingleNode(node, xpathExpr);
```

then you use `Node#setTextContent` ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent%28java.lang.String%29)):

> On setting, any possible children this node may have are removed and, if it the new string is not empty or null, replaced by a single Text node containing the string this attribute is set to.

```
elem.setTextContent("This is the new content. Old content, go away!");
```

Comment: The question is more about how I would find the part of the node to set using an xpath expression.  What is given is a org.w3c.dom.Node object and applying the xpath expression to that.

Comment: I edited the answer: new, you first find the element you care about, then you set its text content.